# SAPUI5/ OPENUI5 javascript view HTML element render

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am new to SAPUI5/ OPENUI5 I have created a javascript view which basically imports several graphs and chart library and like a utility, it creates multiple charts and graphs and tables with icons

below is the code for the same
below is Js (sap ui JS view which creates graph)

```
jQuery.sap.require("some.graph.lib");
jQuery.sap.require("some.util.lib");
jQuery.sap.require("some.other.imports");
(function(){

    sas.hc.ui.core.mvc.JSView.extend(" reports.dashboard.BaseDashboard.prototype.addCrossTab", {

        metadata : {
            properties : {
                chartRequired:false,
                tableDataRequired:false
            },
        },

        rb: sap.ui.getCore().getLibraryResourceBundle("sas.csb.common"),

  reports.dashboard.BaseDashboard.prototype.createGraphics = function (data) {
    //This Function creates barchart, line charts and cross tab tables
        return this.mainContentPane;
    };

    //Some other code to create and render graph
})();
```

I am creating another view in which I am importing above view and making ajax call so that I can create graphs and tables and send it as base64 encoded string to REST API to save into a PDF at the server side.

```
jQuery.sap.require("sas.cscommon.util.JSONUtil");
jQuery.sap.require({modName: "reports.dashboard.MeasureDashboard", type: "view"});

(function(){

    var rb = sap.ui.getCore().getLibraryResourceBundle("sas.csb.backtesting");

    //some other method

     sas.csb.backtesting.ModelList.prototype.downloadModelReport = function(event) { 
        var id = "sample";
            var oView = new reports.dashboard.MeasureDashboard(id, {
                            viewName: "reports.dashboard.MeasureDashboard",
                            chartrequired: true
                        } );


        //Calling REST API to get data
        oView.createGraphics(data);
}
```

How to convert this javascript sapui5 oView Object without displaying it to the user into the HTML element so that I can have the canvas and other graphics to convert into a base 64 encoded string and pass it to REST API to save at server end  ?

I want to access the canvas html element from the view object without rendering the view on screen.

I know there is a renderer attached with sapui5 control and RenderManager in sapui5 but its not helping.

Comment: first of all: do not use JS Views. The reason noone answers your question is that noone uses them, so noone actually wants to look into your issue. Reasons why you sould redo your view in xml and then ask again: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/01/why-do-we-use-xml-views-rather-js-views-in-sapui5/

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the methods for getting the HTML directly were deprecated. But you can create a temporary Element which is not in DOM.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var rm = sap.ui.getCore().createRenderManager();
rm.render(oView, div);
rm.destroy();
var sHTML = div.innerHTML;
```

Comment: I will try this one out and will let you know if it works out.